# How to get the index of the row that is a child row of another table

Tags: jquery

I am having a table nested within a table like this

```
<table class="top" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>
            <table class="nested" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="ii"></td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to get the index of the focused textbox. I used

```
 1. $(this).closest("tr").index();
```

This returned the index of the parent row always.

```
2.$(".ii").focus(function(){
      var tt = cells.closest("tr").index();
      console.log(tt);
  });
```

This returns -1.

How to get the index of the inner table row.How to do this? Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance..

Comment: can u please explain brief ?

Comment: I need to get the index of the focused text box. Usually I use closest() to get the index of a row. But now I have a inner table and I could not get the index of the inner table row that has the text box. @SundarNivash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also find the index of the `tr` that holds the `textbox` by traversing to its parent `table`.

**Code snippets:**

```
$(".ii").focus(function () {
    console.log($(this).closest("table.nested") // `tr`'s parent table
    .find("tr") //Total `tr` that are available in that table
    .index($(this).closest("tr"))); //Here you can get the index
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/umujstvm/1/)